# Dynamically Build Constrained Logic Processor

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably going to be more of a discussion or hypothetical question, but here goes...

Does anyone know of any existing available source (that ideally uses jQuery) to build up logic blocks that the average Joe could use to create a process. Basically what I'm thinking of is that you can put all the building blocks together and then select the action required and the result if the block is true. For example:

```
[IF] {ACTION_A} [AND] {ACTION_2} [THEN] (RESULT_1)

[IF] {ACTION_B} [OR] {ACTION_A} [THEN] (RESULT_2)
```

Where the curly brackets are defined previously in PHP and could (possibly) be selected from a drop down. Maybe something on the lines of what I see outlined here: http://www.surveygizmo.com/survey-support/tutorials/logic-builder-building-skip-jump-and-show-when-logic-rules/ is what I'm looking for, though I don't really want to re-invent the wheel.

I also need to store everything in MySQL, though it may be possible that the [IF] block could be just 1 item, but it could be several. If I had to make this from scratch, I'm not sure on the best way to store multiple items then glue them all together to make one conditional statement.

I'm hoping to get some inspiration here, if not, a lead to somewhere where I do not have to do any re-inventing....

**Update**

For example, maybe one action block is DAY - so the logic blocks/select menus would be like:

```
[IF] {DAY} [EQUALS] 'wednesday' [THEN] (message = 'it is midweek!')
```

or perhaps:

```
[IF] {DAY} [EQUALS] 'friday' [THEN] (message = 'the weekend is almost here!')
```

All user entries would be fully checked and be very limited, so no injections could happen....

**Update 2**

Here's another example I just found, something similar to this http://ksistem.com/jquery/sqlbuilderdemo.htm but not SQL - but nothing to do with databases, just conditions of set actions that I will define.

**Update 3**

Magento comes with something similar, as per this post: [jQuery (or any web tool) Nested Expression Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031805/jquery-or-any-web-tool-nested-expression-builder) (though this was August last year)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Allowing users to essentially inject their own PHP into your server sounds like **bad** news.

Comment: It is in a protected area within an admin area - it would also be very closed in terms of the actions already being defined. Just want the selected users to define how the backend PHP handles tasks based on current conditions. If you like, it is programming, but I'm thinking more on the lines of drag and dropping blocks to generate code (not let them actually do any coding).

Comment: And for another thing, no PHP would be allowed to be entered - just text - any PHP code or MySQL or HTML would be invalid (as checks would be in place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends to a certain extent on what you mean by the term "logic builder."  If all you want to do is provide the ability to construct a series of if-then-else conditionals, where each conditional calls one or more pre-defined functions, then you can easily achieve this through XML (among other methods).

You might have a table row, in which each row looks something like this:

```
Cell 1:  IF
Cell 2:  [dropown containing list of functions] [dropdown containing possible values]
Cell 3:  THEN [dropown containing list of functions] [dropdown containing possible values]
Cell 4:  ELSE [dropown containing list of functions] [dropdown containing possible values]
```

and provide a button to duplicate the row and specify new if-then-else clauses.

If, on the other hand, you are looking to provide the user with a more complete logic builder--for example, if you want to allow the user to also be able to construct the functions that each conditional will call, instead of providing a pre-defined list--you are looking at an entirely different problem.

The reason why if-then-else clauses are easy to specify in a WYSIWYG format is because languages with only such conditionals (and no while loops) are are capable of modelling only a strict subset of the entire class of computable functions; i.e. such languages are not Turing-complete.  If you are looking to provide a fully Turing-complete logic builder--well, I think it would be rather a large undertaking at this point.

Comment: This is something along the lines of my thinking - I admit 'logic builder' isn't the best way to describe it (but I cannot think of a way). Is XML the best way to this this (as opposed to PHP)? Is there a particular way you think I should write this (I'm not that familiar with XML, but can find out/research more into it).

Comment: You can build XML on the client side, and then send it to the server side to be parsed and executed.  Parse the table rows to construct an XML--the schema can be quite simple--and then read and execute that schema in PHP.  (I don't really work with PHP, but I imagine PHP's dynamic variables could come in handy here.)