# Using an array (or xml) to program a function

Tags: php, xml

**Ultimate Goal**

Is to make something like Magento offers - basically a logic builder, and as shown by this post on Stackoverflow: [jQuery (or any web tool) Nested Expression Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031805/jquery-or-any-web-tool-nested-expression-builder) So far I have made jQuery to build a tree and get the data that I want the builder to use, check, and set. Now I just need to parse the checks and add it into various places in a script I'm making - but I am unsure how to process it dynamically so that these checks can be performed, which will lead to some actions occurring/data being changed automatically.

Maybe we can call this dynamic expression processing?

**Original Post**

Forgive me, I know what I would like to do, but have little idea how to do it - so I'm looking for some inspiration. I have allowed a multidimensional array to be generated, and the array would contain certain 'commands' and logic functions, and when a condition is true it is executed.

In it's most basic form, the array would contain a set of if statements, where if the statement were true, then would would proceed to the next array item and go down a level, if it were false, then you'd proceed to the next array item with no children (an unmarried sibling, i guess we could call it). Once there is nothing left to process, since nothing is true, then nothing would happen.

I'd imagine that maybe the best way to 'feed' the data in would be via XML - though would this be possible, I mean, to keep going deeper, else go down, essentially until there is a true condition?

Basically, the array takes the following form (though I not 100% sure I've written it correctly, but I think it looks right :s):

```
[0][0] => array('function' => 'if', 'check' => 'day', 'condition' => 'equals', 'value' => '3');
[0][1][0] => array('function' => 'set', 'name' => 'date_day', 'value' => 'wednesday');
[1][0] => array('function' => 'if', 'check' => 'day', 'condition' => 'equals', 'value' => '4');
[1][1][0] => array('function' => 'set', 'name' => 'date_day', 'value' => 'thursday');
```

So the above would be - if day=3, then set date_day as wednesday; else if day=4, then set date_day as thursday

Which I'd imagine would correspond to (though i have no idea if you can sub item):

```
<items>
    <item>
        <function>if</function>
        <check>day</check>
        <condition>equals</condition>
        <value>3</value>
        <item>
            <function>set</function>
            <name>date_day</name>
            <value>wednesday</value>
        </item>
    </item>
    <item>
        <function>if</function>
        <check>day</check>
        <condition>equals</condition>
        <value>4</value>
        <item>
            <function>set</function>
            <name>date_day</name>
            <value>thursday</value>
        </item>
    </item>
</items>
```

Which would basically make the following statements in a function of some sort:

```
function ($current_data){
  LOOP
    if(FUNCTION == "if"){
      if(CHECK CONDITION VALUE){
         **go to next item deeper in the chain**
      } else {
         **go to sibling item**
      }
    } else if(FUNCTION == "set"){
      define(NAME, VALUE);
    }
  ENDLOOP
}
```

I know the above can be done using the `date()` function, but this is a very basic example. Another example could involve check to see if the colour entered was red, and if it were, then set something based on this colour, else do something else if it were blue. Another could be to set the template to be for US visitors if the US flag was clicked on. The point is that it could basically fulfil any action and do a check and give a result - basically like programming - but where the function data is feed in by PHP or XML

I'm sure there must be something out there that can accomplish this, but I just have no idea were to start exactly, so any assistance would be great - and yes I know there could be some security concerns, but I plan on having checks in place checking that the `checks`, `conditions`, `values`, etc are safe (so this needs to be able to be factored in).

Many many thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish in here? you are making it way too complicated for your self.. hmmm I think what you are looking for is array_map function? I'm not sure what are you trying to do...

Comment: Basically allowing checks to be performed that aren't hardcoded in, so to speak, but could be generated in the form of an array/XML. I know it sounds a little complicated - but basically just need to read the array or xml and perform actions/checks based on its contents.

Comment: aha well I think you are on the right direction all I can say is that you need to use array_map which will help you a lot. so instead of using a loop. you just finish implementing your (function + your array values or xml file).. then load the array with your function using array_map..

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to make a *runtime* or a *compiler*, that works on tokenized instructions. Basically, what any programming language does after it has parsed the source code. Maybe you should read some books going in that direction.

Comment: @MrJ: What does the "set" function check then? In any case, if you need to read an XML document in PHP, there are multiple extensions for that. The PHP docs should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @Lese majeste Set would set a value for an item

Comment: @deceze Yes, I guess it does sound like a runtime or compiler using tokenised instructions, that makes it sound more complicated :S

Comment: @MrJ: If all your inputs are going to follow the same format, which they should if they're just "checks" (i.e. _if x, set y_), then you can avoid writing a full parser/compiler just for such a narrow range of inputs.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté yes - there will be a structure in place - do you have any examples, or something that I could start from? I guess this would be dynamic expression processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay JSON vs. XML aside, here's how I would process that array...

```
$array = xmldecode($xml);
$resultFound = false;
$i = 0;

while(!$resultFound && $i < count($array)) {
    if (myFunction($array[$i]) {
       $resultFound = true;
    }
    $i++;
}

if (!$resultFound) {
    // error condition
}

function myFunction($array) {
    $function = $array[0]['function'];

    switch($function) {
        case 'if':
            $checkVariable = $array[0]['check'];
            $condition = $array[0]['condition'];
            $checkValue = $array[0]['value'];
            switch($checkVariable)
               case 'day':
                   switch($condition) {
                       case 'equals':
                           if (GLOBAL_DAY == $checkValue) {
                               return myFunction($array[1]);
                           } else {
                               return false;
                           }
                           break;
                       case 'less than':
                           if (GLOBAL_DAY < $checkValue) {
                               return myFunction($array[1]);
                           } else {
                               return false;
                           }
                           break;
                   }
               break;
            }
        break;    
        case 'set':
           $setVariable = $array[0]['name'];
           $setValue = $array[0]['value'];
           switch($setVariable) {
                case 'date_day':
                     GLOBAL_DATE_DAY = $setValue;
                     return true;
                     break;
           }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If storage space/transmission speed aren't an issue, I would avoid JSON for configuration files that are meant to be human-editable.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This post has been edited multiple times and I can't leave comments, but I was first responding to fix the array structure, which was then edited to be correct, and I wanted to address the question's notion that XML would be best programming-wise.

Comment: Well, apparently he's generating the code programmatically via a JS interface, so it probably doesn't need to be human-editable. So JSON is probably the correct choice here.

Comment: @Ally Sorry about the edits. After it has been generated, the array/xml needs to be saved so it can be processed outside the configuration page and also be edited later (when needed be) via the interface (not directly in a text editor, etc).

Comment: Thanks - I found this to form the basis of what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very similar to that of form validation, so I would look at some popular jQuery form validation plugins or MVC frameworks like CakePHP. These typically all have stock building blocks for the most common validation rules that the user can easily put together and pass specific arguments to to cover most scenarios.

The notable difference between your problem and these examples is that form validation frameworks are aimed at developers, so they can simply write custom functions if they need to glue multiple rules together to form a more complex rule. However, you can still achieve something that works for probably 98% of all use cases by doing something like:

```
$offers = array(
  'pet feed sale' => array(
    'category' => array(1, 2, 3)
    'total' => '>100',
    'weekday' => array('mon', 'wed')
    'set' => array(
      'discount' => 80
      'shipping' => 0
    )
  ),
  'medication sale' => array(
    'category' => 4
    'date' => '2012-1-28',
    'set' => array(
      'discount' => 50
    )
  )
);
```

And if the user needs apply more complex pricing structures then they could, for instance, break the "pet feed sale" rule into 3 offers, one for dog food, one for cat food, and one for fish food. There might be more repetition, but it makes it much easier to implement than a full parser.

Also, most non-programmers probably handle repetition a lot better than complicated logic and control flow.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and template of keeping everything consistent, I've now implemented what you have outlined